# How to connect to the Parse Javascript API? (502 error)

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am building a chatroom-type app using the Parse Javascript API. The task is to get some data from Parse, display it, add user input to the messages, and send it right back to parse.

The problem is I am not being able to see the data from parse, and receive a 502 error. I am a bit newer to javascript, so any advice on how to accomplish this, or any mistakes you may see in my code, would be fantastic. I also commented out my code the best I could. Thanks for the help.

Here is my code;

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    delete Chat.display;
    delete Chat.send;
    delete Chat.fetch;

    var my_messages = $('ul.messages')
  //fetches data from parse
    var myChat = function() {
        $.ajax({
      url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
      dataType: "json",
      success: console.log("Success"),
            function message(a) {
        my_messages.append('<ul>' + a +'</ul>'); //adds ul 'text' to messages
          };
       });
     };   

  myChat(); // call mychat


       $('button.send').on('click', function() { // when user clicks send

        // send post to
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          data: JSON.stringify({text: $('input.draft').val()}), // stringify the text on value input.draft
          function(message){
            window.location.reload(1) //refresh every 3 seconds 
          });
      });
});

</script>
```

Comment: I haven't used the Parse JS API, but shouldn't you be using some kind of auth headers somewhere? How will parse know who the request is coming from without your client id (or equivalent)

Comment: Try putting `console.log("success"),` inside `function message(a){`

Comment: @JohnP it's a pre-existing "library", at the top of my html file I added the auth header :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error in both of your success functions of $.ajax calls. In the first ajax call you have places **console.log**, which should be inside the success callback. In the second one u haven't even added **success:** callback.

Try below updated code

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    delete Chat.display;
    delete Chat.send;
    delete Chat.fetch;

    var my_messages = $('ul.messages');

    var myChat = function() {
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          dataType: "json",
          success:function message(a) {
                console.log("Success")
                $.each(a,function(i,item){
                   my_messages.append('<ul>' + item.username +'</ul>'); //adds ul 'text' to messages
                });
          }
       });
     };   

    myChat(); // call mychat

    $('button.send').on('click', function() { // when user clicks send
        // send post to
        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
           data: JSON.stringify({text: $('input.draft').val()}), // stringify the text on value input.draft
           success:function(message){
              window.location.reload(1) //refresh every 3 seconds 
           }
      });
    });
 });
```

Comment: While you are correct on the syntax errors, it might be clearer if you point out what they are, instead of just saying 'replace your code with this code'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That definitely helped, and in google's console I can see the "success", so I am now targeting the API. However, in the "app" I only see a list with [object Object]. I linked to an image of what I am seeing on imgur; http://i.imgur.com/08xYaoo.png

Comment: instead of console.log("Success"), log your result. ie,  console.log(a) to check what you are getting as result.

Comment: @subashSelvaraj, wow, great insight! When I did that, I see an array of objects which are supposed to be the objects I am displaying on the chat. Any idea on how to get those objects "out", and display them?

Comment: post your result object here so that we can get it out.

Comment: @SubashSelvaraj here is a link to what I see on imgur; http://i.imgur.com/aKnP7Pr.png . I get a bullet with [object Object] . However, the object is object {results Array[10]} and when I click on the carrot I see "0: Object" then with the attributes; created at, object ID, text, updated at, username. I'm trying to display the username and the text. Here is another image; http://i.imgur.com/h2PNXg4.png

Comment: @subashselvaraj thanks! I tried a loop, but an each block seems more efficient. However, I got an error. The dev console said Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } on line 23, which is referring to $.each(a,item){ . I checked, and your code seems to be fine in terms of brackets. Any idea on why it comes up with an error?

Comment: Thanks so much @subashSelvaraj! If you're ever in LA, I'll buy you a beer :)

Comment: Will let you know once I come there :)